# Descargar página HTML completa con Perl

Tags: html, perl, google-sites

Estoy intentando crear un script en Perl para descargar un conjunto de páginas web que requieren mis credenciales (usuario y contraseña). La web está alojada en sites.google. He intentado lo siguiente:

```
use LWP::UserAgent;
$ua = new LWP::UserAgent;
$req = new HTTP::Request GET => 'https://sites.google.com/my_web';
$req->authorization_basic('my_user', 'my_password');
$output = $ua->request($req)->as_string;
print $output;
```

Obtengo código HTML, pero no el contenido HTML de la página en cuestión. Necesito un módulo especial para esto?

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que te refieres a los elementos de la página (imágenes, sonidos, vídeos).

Debes interpretar el código HTML y hacer una petición como la que has hecho, pero para cada elemento encontrado.

Quizás, con una expresión regular (buscando por los atributos 'href') te valga para encontrar esos URL. Debes distinguir los casos de estar puestos en forma absoluta (con el 'http://' o con el '/' delante) o relativa.

Una forma más cómoda es usar la herramienta 'lwp-mirror' que viene instalada por defecto con Perl.

https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/libwww-perl/bin/lwp-mirror

Comment: En realidad me refiero al texto de la página, concretamente de múltiples páginas HTML que tienen una dirección común: https://sites.google.com/my_web/ejemplo1   https://sites.google.com/my_web/ejemplo2   https://sites.google.com/my_web/ejemplo3, ... Probaré con esa herramienta que me comentas. Gracias.